# value not getting bind in angular

Tags: angular, data-binding

Here I am having two fields, one is input and one is dropdown. For dropdown, values coming from api. When I enter number in input field, after clicking on enter key, it will call function and there 2 conditions are there, If condition1 matches

```
this.cardModel.payType.value="Visa";
```

and this value should show as a default value of the dropdown.

if condition2 matches then

```
 this.cardModel.payType.value="Master Card";
```

and those assigned values should be show as a default value 
of the dropdown. But the value is not displaying though I have given `[(ngModel)]="cardModel.crd_no.value` in html file. Not getting Where I have done mistake. Plz help me!!

html

```
<input name="crd_no" (keydown.enter)="youFuncToCheck(card_number)" [(ngModel)]="cardModel.crd_no.value"  type="text" class="form-control">


    <select class="form-control" name="typeOfPayment"  [(ngModel)]="cardModel.payType.value">
     <option *ngFor="let itm of payType" value={{itm.key}}>{{itm.display}}</option>
    </select>
```

ts file

```
youFuncToCheck(card_number){
card_number=this.payType.crd_no.value

 // visa
 var re = new RegExp("^4");
 if (card_number.match(re) != null){
  this.cardModel.payType.value="Visa";
}

var re=new RegExp("^5[1-5][0-9]{0,14}|^(222[1-9]|2[3-6]\\d{2}|27[0-1]d|2720)[0-9]{0,12}");
   if(card_number.match(re) != null)
     this.cardModel.payType.value="Master Card";
   }
```

Comment: Can you put up the code on StackBlitz for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Note the below example where the value in select and value in the option are same. Please make sure both the values are same and also of the same type. This way you can make a default selection possible

```
<select  class='form-control' 
            (change)="ChangingValue($event)" [value]='46'>
      <option value='47'>47</option>
      <option value='46'>46</option>
      <option value='45'>45</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some basic code using `ngModel` in `select` element :

html file

```
  <select class="form-control" name="typeOfPayment"  [(ngModel)]="cardModel.payType.value">
     <option *ngFor="let itm of payType" [ngValue]={{itm.key}}>{{itm.display}}</option>
  </select>
```

ts file:

```
     cardModel.payType.value = ''
```